# Comparing two arrays of type ITweet

Tags: c#, arrays, comparison

I'd like to compare two arrays of type `ITweet` notice that this class isn't mine, and seems it doesn't have Equality Comparer inside.

```
ITweet[] tweets = await GetLikes();
ITweet[] newTweets = await GetLikes();

if (!tweets.SequenceEqual(newTweets))
{
    // Notice that this won't work
}

newTweets.Except(tweets); // This neither
```

How could I compare them? I'd like to use Except since I do need those different ocurrences. What'd be the correct approach?

Update: I noticed `ITWeet` implements `IEquatable` but for some reason `Equals` don't work neither.

Comment: What's `ITweet`? How do you compare two `ITweet` objects?

Comment: Here's the [ITweet](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/blob/91cdf83b87f6c0c75d7ece6a13fce792d820e3c8/src/Tweetinvi.Core/Public/Models/Interfaces/ITweet.cs#L14) class.

Comment: Look at [this](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/blob/91cdf83b87f6c0c75d7ece6a13fce792d820e3c8/src/Tweetinvi.Core/Core/Models/Tweet.cs#L386), they haven't implemented `Equals` at all, it's just a reference comparision.

Comment: @shingo Oh, didn't see thanks! since it isn't my own class is there a way I could implement it?

Comment: Create your own comparer that implements `IEqualityComparer<ITweet>`, then use `tweets.SequenceEqual(newTweets, comparer)` (or `tweets.Except(newTweets, comparer)`)